# Specify that another field should have the same value as the id field on INSERT

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers

In a Postgres table I have an `id` field (system generated identifier) and an `other_id` field. During insert, if the `other_id` field is not supplied I'd like the `other_id` to take on the value of the id field. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I wonder why some one -1 you... I hate when people do that with out comment

Comment: That's what triggers are for

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a design, where `other_id` stays `NULL` instead of storing the same value redundantly. You can emulate your current design in queries with:

```
COALESCE(other_id, id) As other_id
```

If that's not an option, create a **trigger** `BEFORE INSERT`, that either throws an error for violating inserts or just overwrites `other_id` regardless. That's pretty simple, really. Or, according to this: `if the other_id field is not supplied`, do that only if the column is still `NULL`.

For a table named `tbl`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_tbl_ins_bef()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF NEW.other_id IS NULL THEN -- only if still NULL
   NEW.other_id := NEW.id;   -- or just overwrite without IF ...
END IF;
RETURN NEW;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_bef
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_tbl_ins_bef()
```